# Rendering pandas DataFrame to html on Flask

Tags: python, pandas, flask, jinja2

Can anyone give me some tips or links to investigate how to remedy a `df.describe()` in a web browser thru a flask app?

For example if I `print(df.describe())` in IPython this comes thru in a nice format:

```
     kW
count  28219.000000
mean     134.723654
std       46.849081
min       24.300000
25%       91.300000
50%      135.900000
75%      168.600000
max      313.900000
```

But if I attempt this with a render template pass the data as string::

```
maxStatsStr = str(df.describe())

resp = make_response(render_template('table.html',
maxStatsStr=maxStatsStr))

return resp
```

To the front end HTML file with Jinja syntax:

```
<p>{{maxStatsStr}}</p>
```

This shows up in the browser

```
kW count 34880.000000 mean 79.687947 std 42.909287 min 12.200000 25% 38.800000 50% 73.400000 75% 113.200000 max 292.800000
```

Would a better method be creating like a table somehow, and using a for loop with Jinja to display the data? On the backend I just dont know how to prepare a `df.describe()` to be rendered as a table, like this below:

```
{% for table in tables %}
            {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

**FINAL CODE USED**

```
statsInfoStr = df.describe().to_html()

resp = make_response(render_template('table.html',
maxDateStr=maxDateStr,

tables=[statsInfoStr], titles=df.describe().T))
return resp
```

`table.html` jinja to loop over data:

```
        <h2>Summary Statistics</h2>
        {% for table in tables %}
                    {{ table|safe }}
        {% endfor %}

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you already looked into [`pd.DataFrame.to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html?highlight=to_html#pandas.DataFrame.to_html)? If you want to pretty it up, you can always look at the [Styling Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

Comment: Thanks. This works `df.describe().to_html(classes='data')`

Comment: But how would I make column names out of the `df.describ()` for example `count  
mean, std, min, 25%, 50%, 75%, max `?

Comment: Ideally you'll want to manipulate the dataframe structure before converting.  In your case, perhaps `df.describe().T`? If you have a more concrete [mre] with I/O it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I can get from here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can utilize the [`pd.DataFrame.to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html?highlight=to_html#pandas.DataFrame.to_html) method to get the frame converted to html.

You might even use the [Styling Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) to pretty it up before converting to html.

Then, you probably want to use the [`render_template_string`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.render_template_string) function instead.

e.g.:

```
def some_flask_func(...):
    # ... your other codes ... #

    # If you just want to get the vanilla structure: 
    df_html = df.describe().to_html()

    # or, if you want to use Styler instead:
    df_html = df.describe().style.apply(some_style_func).render()

    # render directly from string:
    resp = make_response(render_template_string(df_html)
    return resp
```

Comment: One more newb question, I posted the code that worked. I ended up using a table and Jinja to loop over the data. Is it possible to display many tables in the `resp = make_response`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with `Jinja` but I'd wager you want to join or format multiple tables before you render it.  Seeing as your `tables=[...]` take a list, I'm guessing it should support multiple table objects if your template supports it.  If not, I suggest you put it as a new question with relevant tags to attract other answerers.